# How to generate code coverage report with jest and detox?

Tags: react-native, npm, detox

I'm using jest for unit tests and detox for some automation (using jest as test runner). Here's my setup in `package.json`

```
"jest": {
        "preset": "react-native",
        "collectCoverage": true,
        "coverageReporters": [
            "json",
            "html"
        ],
        "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
            "/node_modules/",
            "/.history/",
            "/e2e/"
        ]
    },
"detox": {
        "test-runner": "jest",
        "runner-config": "e2e/config.json",
        "configurations": ...
    }
```

I want to see the combined code coverage, how should I do it?

Comment: Hi have you find out a way to produce coverage for Detox tests?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just got an answer from detox's development team that this might never be possible to do

> Not sure how we can add coverage by Detox since the tests don't run your JS code in node. Instead, it commands the device and the app to do stuff, and then asserts that something has changed in the native view hierarchy on the device/simulator.
>
> I believe this will never be possible.
>
> link- https://github.com/wix/detox/issues/470

UDPATE: Looks like https://github.com/wix/detox/issues/470 has been reopened and folks are actively working on making Detox test coverage possible! Never say never :D